# Is there a way to declare a typescript class type that is similar to `any`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm slowly converting a project to typescript and there is a dependency I'd like to add *some* types to via global.d.ts.

For example, that dependency has SomeClass I'd like to declare with types, but another dozen other classes I'd like to skip for now.

But, when I add types for SomeClass, it causes everything else to become errors "no exported member".

Is there a way to skip the others or declare them as any for now?  Doing `export type SkipThisClassForNow = any` doesn't play nice with new SkipThisClassForNow().

Without any type declarations, typescript treats everything imported from that dependency as `any` and works.  Is there a way to force typescript to behave that way?  Or are type declarations like this none or all?

Comment: Are these "dozen other classes" in the same file? Based off of your description it sounds like they are.

Comment: any code samples would help

Answer (score 0):

The example below exports `Module` which has [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) which will give the type `any` for any key that is not defined. Keys which are defined will export the defined type.

```js
declare module 'dependency' {
    class SomeClass {
        constructor(a: boolean)
    }

    interface Module {
        [key: string]: any

        SomeClass: typeof SomeClass
    }

    const module: Module;
    export = module;
}
```